# How can i authenticate with curl and grante_type with php

Tags: php, curl

I want to authenticate with a login and password using curl and grant_type

```
    <?php

        $clientID= 'ddd@ddd.fr';
        $clientSecret='1234';
        $data =
            'client_id=' . $clientID . '&' .
            'client_secret=' . $clientSecret . '&' .
            "grant_type=client_credentials";

        $url = "https://xxxxxx.fr:4568/connect/token";
        $headers = array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
            "grant_type=client_credentials"
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientID . ':' . $clientSecret);
        $x = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        var_dump($x);

  ?>
```

when i started this script it show me this error:

object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'error' => string 'invalid_request' (length=15)
  public 'error_description' => string 'Multiple client credentials cannot be specified.' (length=48)

if someone know how can i  resudre this problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: exemple of call with CURL [curl -X POST  -d "grant_type=password&password=1234&username=ddd@ddd.fr"  https://xxxxxx.fr:4568/connect/token ]  my goal is to call it from PHP

Comment: the curl exemple works well , but the php code doesn't work even after converting php code to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded format